# Formatting a function within componentDidMount() - syntax question

Tags: reactjs

This component renders a clock with a visible seconds ticker. Here, `componentDidMount()` calls the `tick()` function every second to re-render the current time.

Why is it written as: 
`setInterval(() => (func, interval)` instead of just 
`setInterval(func, interval)`?

- I understand arrow function syntax, where it's `const funcName = (params) => do something`
- But here, `timerID` is the function name, `setInterval` is what we want it to do, the params are `this.tick, 1000` - what's the point of the additional `() =>`?

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // why this?
        this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
    // instead of this?
        this.timerID = setInterval(this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely wrong:

```
this.timerID = setInterval(this.tick(), 1000);
```

because it will invoke `this.tick` *immediately*, on mount, rather than passing a *reference* to `this.tick`.

If you were thinking of

```
this.timerID = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
```

this will fail because the callback then will no longer have its `this` bound to the instance. It's similar to why the following fails:

```js
class X {
  prop = 'prop';
  fn() {
    return this.prop;
  }
}
const x = new X();
const callback = x.fn;
console.log(callback());
```

The calling context of `this` (or `x`) is not automatically preserved; when a function is passed as a callback, you need to make sure the function has the correct reference to `this` *when you pass it in*, because the callback itself very often will not.

With the interval, the interval callback is called with a `this` of the global object, or `undefined`. This isn't an issue when the working code is used:

```
() => this.tick()
```

because the arrow function means the `this` is inherited from the outer scope, which is the instance. But with an unbound method like `Clock.prototype.tick`, passing it as a callback without any changes will result in it being called without a calling context, such that the `this` inside doesn't refer to what you wanted.

An anonymous callback like `() => this.tick()` fixes this problem.

Another option is to bind the callback to the `this` you need as you pass it:

```
setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
```

Another option is to bind the callback to the instance ahead of time, like in the constructor:

```
this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
```

Or with a class field:

```
this.tick = () => {
  this.setState({ date: new Date() });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

second option you are invoking the function, not passing the function. you actually can do:

```
this.timerID = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
```

but you have to bind `this`for `tick` function works as expected. for that you can define it as arrow function:

```
  tick = () => {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
```